# ScriptUi custom shape button with OnDraw

Tags: javascript, photoshop, adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

I wrote a script with a dialog with custom round buttons (something like the official adobe ones).
Being ignorant of mathematics, I drew the button with straight lines, like this:

```
    ButtonPanel ();
    function ButtonPanel () {
        var Panel = new Window ("dialog");
        Panel.text = "Panel";
        var Button = Panel.add ("button");
        Button.text = "Exit";
        Button.preferredSize.width = 170;
        Button.onClick = function () {
                Panel.close ();
            }
        Draw (Button);
        Panel.show ();
        function Draw (Obj) {
            if (Obj.type == "button") {
                Obj.graphics.foregroundColor = Obj.graphics.newPen (Obj.graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 1, 1], 1);
                Obj.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont (Obj.graphics.font.name, "Bold", Obj.graphics.font.size);
                Obj.onDraw = function (Event) {
                    with (Obj) {
                        graphics.drawOSControl ();
                        graphics.newPath ();
                        graphics.moveTo ((size[0] / 340) * 25, (size[1] / 50) * 0);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 17.73, (size[1] / 50) * 1.06);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 11.98, (size[1] / 50) * 3.65);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 7.32, (size[1] / 50) * 7.32);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 3.65, (size[1] / 50) * 11.98);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 1.06, (size[1] / 50) * 17.73);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 0, (size[1] / 50) * 25);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 1.06, (size[1] / 50) * 32.26);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 3.65, (size[1] / 50) * 38.02);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 7.32, (size[1] / 50) * 42.68);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 11.98, (size[1] / 50) * 46.35);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 17.73, (size[1] / 50) * 48.93);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 25, (size[1] / 50) * 50);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 315, (size[1] / 50) * 50);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 322.25, (size[1] / 50) * 48.93);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 328, (size[1] / 50) * 46.35);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 332.66, (size[1] / 50) * 42.68);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 336.34, (size[1] / 50) * 38.02);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 338.92, (size[1] / 50) * 32.26);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 340, (size[1] / 50) * 25);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 338.92, (size[1] / 50) * 17.73);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 336.34, (size[1] / 50) * 11.98);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 332.66, (size[1] / 50) * 7.32);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 328, (size[1] / 50) * 3.65);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 322.25, (size[1] / 50) * 1.06);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 315, (size[1] / 50) * 0);
                        graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 25, (size[1] / 50) * 0);
                        graphics.closePath ();
                        graphics.fillPath (graphics.newBrush (graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 0, 0]));
                        graphics.closePath ();
                        if (text) {
                            graphics.drawString (text, (graphics.newPen (graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 1, 1], 1)), (size[0] - graphics.measureString (text, graphics.font, size[0])[0]) / 2, (size[1] - graphics.measureString (text, graphics.font, size[1])[1]) / 2, graphics.font);
                            }
                        if (Event.mouseOver) {
                            graphics.fillPath (graphics.newBrush (graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 1, 1]));
                            if (text) {
                                graphics.drawString (text, (graphics.newPen (graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 0, 0], 1)), (size[0] - graphics.measureString (text, graphics.font, size[0])[0]) / 2, (size[1] - graphics.measureString (text, graphics.font, size[1])[1]) / 2, graphics.font);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However I have seen on [this site](https://sites.google.com/view/youuu4/HowToWrite/graphicsobject) that it is possible to draw the various shapes with a geometric formulas.
Does anyone know how the half circles on the sides of the button could be drawn with "geometric calculations"?

---

**UPDATE**

After messing with the stib's code and the linked site's one, I came up with this final script:

```
    ButtonPanel ();
    function ButtonPanel () {
        var Panel = new Window ("dialog");
        Panel.text = "Panel";
        var Button = Panel.add ("button");
        Button.text = "Exit";
        Button.preferredSize.width = 170;
        Button.onClick = function () {
                Panel.close ();
            }
        Draw (Button);
        Panel.show ();
        function Draw (Obj) {
            if (Obj.type == "button") {
                Obj.graphics.foregroundColor = Obj.graphics.newPen (Obj.graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 1, 1], 1);
                Obj.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont (Obj.graphics.font.name, "Bold", Obj.graphics.font.size);
                Obj.onDraw = function (Event) {
                    with (Obj) {
                        graphics.drawOSControl ();
                        graphics.newPath ();
                        graphics.moveTo (12.5, 0);
                        for (var i = 0; i < Math.PI; i += Math.PI / 100) {
                            graphics.lineTo ((-12.5 * Math.sin (i)) + 12.5, (-12.5 * Math.cos (i)) + 12.5);
                            }
                            graphics.lineTo (157.5, 25);
                        for (var i = 0; i < Math.PI; i += Math.PI / 100) {
                            graphics.lineTo ((12.5 * Math.sin (i)) + 157.5, (12.5 * Math.cos (i)) + 12.5);
                            }
                        graphics.lineTo (12.5, 0);
                        graphics.closePath ();
                        graphics.fillPath (graphics.newBrush (graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 0, 0]));
                        if (text) {
                            graphics.drawString (text, (graphics.newPen (graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 1, 1], 1)), (size[0] - graphics.measureString (text, graphics.font, size[0])[0]) / 2, (size[1] - graphics.measureString (text, graphics.font, size[1])[1]) / 2, graphics.font);
                            }
                        if (Event.mouseOver) {
                            graphics.fillPath (graphics.newBrush (graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 1, 1]));
                            if (text) {
                                graphics.drawString (text, (graphics.newPen (graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 0, 0], 1)), (size[0] - graphics.measureString (text, graphics.font, size[0])[0]) / 2, (size[1] - graphics.measureString (text, graphics.font, size[1])[1]) / 2, graphics.font);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oof. You know that loops are a thing right?

The site you link to is just using straight lines but is generating each segment using the formula for the various curves. The formula for a point on the circumference of a circle given the angle `θ` from the x axis to the point, and the radius `r` is `[ cos(θ), sin(θ) ] * r`. You can decide how many segments you want in the half circle and make a loop to call that formula that many times.

```
    function halfCircle(
        radius, //radius of the half circle
        segStart, //coordinates of the start of the segment
        angleStart, // angle of the start of the segment from the positive x axis
        numSegments //how many segments to draw
    ){

        var circle = {
            x: function(i, r){ return Math.cos(i) * r},
            y: function(i, r){ return Math.cos(i) * r}
        }

        var g = this.graphics;
        g.newPath();
        g.moveTo(segStart);

        var increment = Math.pi / numSegments; //Pi in radians is 180°
        var offset = angleStart * Math.pi / 180;
        for (var i = 0; i < numSegments; i++){
            g.lineTo(
                circle.x(i * increment + offset, radius) + segStart, 
                circle.y(i * increment + offset, radius) + segStart
            );
        }
    }

    halfCircle(340, [123,456], 123, 45);
```

Comment: Yes, I know loops, but if I didn't know what to do with them they were probably useless to me, that's why I drew them by hand in a rough way.

Comment: I had guessed how the site's script worked, but I didn't know the mathematical formulas and how to apply them.
After messing around with your script and the site's one, I managed to get something done.
There is still something I don't understand in your script.
Why are the curly braces missing after the parentheses, and why are there two radius?

Comment: they're typos. Have fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the values of size[0] which is 170 and size[1], which is 25 you can rewrite the semi circle code with the exact values:

```
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 17.73, (size[1] / 50) * 1.06);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 11.98, (size[1] / 50) * 3.65);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 7.32, (size[1] / 50) * 7.32);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 3.65, (size[1] / 50) * 11.98);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 1.06, (size[1] / 50) * 17.73);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 0, (size[1] / 50) * 25);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 1.06, (size[1] / 50) * 32.26);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 3.65, (size[1] / 50) * 38.02);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 7.32, (size[1] / 50) * 42.68);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 11.98, (size[1] / 50) * 46.35);
graphics.lineTo ((size[0] / 340) * 17.73, (size[1] / 50) * 48.93);
```

or simply

```
graphics.lineTo (8.865, 0.53);
graphics.lineTo (5.99, 1.825);
graphics.lineTo (3.66, 3.66);
graphics.lineTo (1.825, 5.99);
graphics.lineTo (0.53, 8.865);
graphics.lineTo (0, 12.5);
graphics.lineTo (0.53, 8.865);
graphics.lineTo (1.825, 5.99);
graphics.lineTo (3.66, 3.66);
graphics.lineTo (5.99, 1.825);
graphics.lineTo (8.865, 0.53);
```

So it's now simply a matter of substituting the x an y values with `[ cos(θ), sin(θ) ] * r` as stib has shown you in his much better (and quicker) answer.

Comment: Yes, I already knew I could enter the correct values (that mess of a script was a calculation I had done by hand to get something similar to a curve), but most likely the values are approximate and the result is not drawn that well. So I was looking for a way to put them automatically.